# Sun's CodeModel support in future version of JDK (JDK 7,8 and OpenJDK)

Tags: jaxb, code-generation, java, java-6

We are developing code generation tool using [CodeModel](http://codemodel.java.net). This library is provided by Sun and being used by JAXB to generate code.

Could support for it be dropped in future versions like JDK 7 and OpenJDK?
Should we thus write our own library for code generation or continue using Sun's library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its certainly possible that a future JAXB implementation would switch to a different way of generating code, making CodeModel obsolete. But nothing is stopping you from using the current version on newer JDKs, backward compatibility is taken very seriously by oracle and sun before. The code is open source so no one would be stopping you from fixing bugs either.

CodeModel probably won't get extended to support newer language features like Strings in switch in java 7 or lambda in java 8 unless these would be useful to the JAXB implementation.

Comment: Is there already a new framework to replace CodeModel ?

Comment: @pith: As far as I know codemodel is still used by JAXB. If you need additional features then the mailing list or issue tracker at their project site would be the place to start.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I don't need new features, I only wanted to know if codeModel was deprecated.